# How to remove screens (unmount component) from react native drawer-navigator on log out?How to reload Components Data?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-component

I am using react navigation v3 in my app, I use stack navigator inside drawer navigator ,On the click of logout I navigate to login screen with clearing storage of user, But whenever I login again , Main component dose not call componentWillMount or componentDidMount method , and displays Previously loaded data on it. here is my code >

```
const screens = {
  login: { screen: Login },
  dashboard: { screen: Dashboard },
  patientList:{screen:StackNav},
  headerComponent:HeaderComponent
 }

  const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
     screens,
      {
       initialRouteName: 'login',
      contentComponent: Sidebar
       }
     );

    App  = createAppContainer(MyDrawerNavigator);
    export default App;
```

StackNav ==

```
export default createStackNavigator({
     PatientList,
     PatientDetails
 });
```

Logout Function ==

```
  localStorageService.removeAllKeys().then((res) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate(route, { isLogin: 'N' })
  });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

put this in navigationOptions of drawer navigator

```js
unmountInactiveRoutes: true
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Using in a component created with `createDrawerNavigator`.

Comment: It works for me. Thanks! Using react-navigation 5.1.0 (via Expo)

Answer (score 18):

## In React Navigation 5.x

use `unmountOnBlur`

```js
<Drawer.Screen
    name={...}
    component={...}
    unmountOnBlur={true}
    options={{unmountOnBlur: true}}
/>
```

Comment: what if i dont need a drawer and just want to use stackNavigator?

Comment: only this part is sufficient *options={{unmountOnBlur: true}}*

Answer (score 0):

As [Daniyal's awnser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55326077/3021610) complementation: I've introduced the configuration inside createDrawerNavigator() configs as above:

```
const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
{
  Home:{
    screen: Home
  },
  Login:{
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: () => null
    }
  }
},
{
  unmountInactiveRoutes: true
});
```

And now all pages are working withouth any "cache".